# How To change box shadow range in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, function, range, onchange

how i change the box shadow width this code

```
        $('#Range1').change(function () {
            $('.divwidth').css({ boxShadowX: this.value + 'px' });
            $('.divwidth').css({ 'boxShadowY': this.value + 'px' });
            $('.divwidth').css({ 'boxShadowBlur': this.value + 'px' });
        });
```

this.value + 'px' = its avalue of html range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery before 1.8

```
$('.divwidth').css({
            'color' : 'black',
            'background' : 'white',
            'border-radius' : '15px',
            'box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444',
            '-moz-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444',
        });
```

After 1.8 you can use

```
$('.divwidth').css({ boxShadow: '1px 3px 6px #444' })
```

And what you look for is:

```
$('.divwidth').css({ boxShadow: '1px ' + this.value + 'px ' + '6px #444' })
```

And the boxShadow property is `boxShadow : horizontal(X) vertical(Y) blur shadow`

Comment: tahnk you Razvan i am undestud how it work its really simple right now :)

Comment: no problem, we're here to help. if my answer helped you, i recommend you to rate it or to accept it. have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Lucking some example from your question, but try this one.

`$('#Range1').change(function () {
     $('.divwidth').css('boxShadowX', $(this).width());
     $('.divwidth').css('boxShadowY', $(this).width());
     $('.divwidth').css('boxShadowBlur', $(this).width());
});`

or

`$('#Range1').change(function () {
     $('.divwidth').css({boxShadowX: $(this).width(), $(this).width(), $(this).width()});
});`

PX is not necessary since it is calculated on PX

refer here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

In css boxShedowX boxShedowY,boxShadowBlur  style not

use this
and set this numbers dinamic ;

```
.css({ boxShadow: '1px 3px 6px #444' });
```